# XML serialization reference - duplicate

Tags: java, c#, xml, serialization

[Java or C#] I have some problem with serialization. How not to duplicate all the information about the object and use only reference?

Sample classes:

```
class Author {
  public String id;
  public String name;
}

class Book {
  public String id;
  public Author author;
  public String title;
}
```

And I have to format the output file like here:

```
<store>
  <authors>
   <author id="PK">
     <name>Philip Kindred</name>
    </author>
  </authors>

  <books>
    <book id="u1">
      <author>PK</author> <!--  use only ID -->
      <title>Ubik</title>
    </book>
  </books>
</store>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "duplicate all the information about the object"?  Do you mean, "how can I avoid manually hand-coding XML output for each field in my classes"?  If so, in c# you can use [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to automatically serialize to and deserialize from XML using reflection.

Comment: That's not the problem. In book statement I don't want to duplicate every time author object but use reference to single one (e.g. by author ID).

Comment: The problem in hand is clearly how to persist an aggregation relationship in XML. Given the hierarchical nature of XML (very good to express composition but not aggregation) that always require extra logic to make it work, see one possible answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing with the problem of representing aggregation instead of composition relationship within XML. XML serialization is extremely simple when you are persisting parent-child relationships where the parent owns the child (i.e. composition). In this case, a book has one author (or more), but doesn't own it, because one author can be the writer of many other books.

In that case you can do something similar to what is done in databases, that is, have two separate entries and express the relationship via foreign key. See an example below:

```
[Serializable]
public class Author
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public String Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Book
{
    private Author _author;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Author Author
    {
        get { return _author; }
        set
        {
            _author = value;
            AuthorId = _author != null ? _author.Id : null;
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public String Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("author")]
    public String AuthorId { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("title")]
    public String Title { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Store
{
    [XmlArray("authors")]
    [XmlArrayItem("author", Type = typeof(Author))]
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("books")]
    [XmlArrayItem("book", Type = typeof(Book))]
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public Store()
    {
        Books = new List<Book>();
        Authors = new List<Author>();
    }
}


internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create some authors
        var authors = new List<Author>
        {
            new Author{Id="PK", Name="Philip Kindred"},
            new Author{Id="WS", Name="William Shakespeare"},
        };

        // Create some books linked to the authors
        var books = new List<Book>
        {
            new Book{Id = "U1", Author = authors[0], Title = "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?"},
            new Book{Id = "U2", Author = authors[1], Title = "Romeo and Juliet"}
        };

        var store = new Store {Authors = authors, Books = books};

        var success = Serialiser.SerialiseToXml(store, "store.xml");

        // Deserialize the data from XML
        var store2 = Serialiser.DeserialseFromXml<Store>("store.xml");

        // Resolve the actual Author instances from the saved IDs (foreign key equivalent in databases)
        foreach (var book in store2.Books)
            book.Author = store2.Authors.FirstOrDefault(author => author.Id == book.AuthorId);

        // Now variable 'store' and 'store2' have the same equivalent data
    }
}

// Helper class to serialize and deserialize the data to XML file
public static class Serialiser
{
    public static bool SerialiseToXml(object obj, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            var ws = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize,
                NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
                Indent = true,
                NewLineOnAttributes = false
            };
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, ws))
                xs.Serialize(writer, obj);

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static T DeserialseFromXml<T>(string filename) where T : new()
    {
        var typeofT = typeof(T);
        try
        {
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeofT);
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(filename))
                return (T)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

The 'store.xml' will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Store xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<authors>
    <author id="PK">
    <name>Philip Kindred</name>
    </author>
    <author id="WS">
    <name>William Shakespeare</name>
    </author>
</authors>
<books>
    <book id="U1">
    <author>PK</author>
    <title>Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?</title>
    </book>
    <book id="U2">
    <author>WS</author>
    <title>Romeo and Juliet</title>
    </book>
</books>
</Store>
```

Answer (score 1):

**c# answer**

You can do this if you have some larger container class that can manage cross-references between objects.  In your case, you seem to have a `Store` object that could serve this purpose.  The `Store` maintains dictionaries of books and authors by name; the `Book` remembers the `id` of its author, and the actual `Author` is fetched from the store as required.  Of course, this requires both `Author` and `Book` to know the store in which they exist.

An example implementation might be as follows:

```
public class Author
{
    string id;
    Store store;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Store Store {
        get {
            return store;
        }
        set {
            if (store != null && id != null)
                store.Authors.Remove(id);
            this.store = value;
            if (store != null && id != null)
                store.Authors[id] = this;
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (store != null && id != null)
                store.Authors.Remove(id);
            this.id = value;
            if (store != null && id != null)
                store.Authors[id] = this;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    string authorId;
    string id;
    Store store;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Store Store
    {
        get
        {
            return store;
        }
        set
        {
            if (store != null && id != null)
                store.Books.Remove(id);
            this.store = value;
            if (store != null && id != null)
                store.Books[id] = this;
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (store != null && id != null)
                store.Books.Remove(id);
            this.id = value;
            if (store != null && id != null)
                store.Books[id] = this;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("author")]
    public string AuthorID
    {
        get
        {
            return authorId;
        }
        set
        {
            authorId = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Author Author
    {
        get
        {
            if (store == null)
                return null;
            if (AuthorID == null)
                return null;
            return store.Authors[AuthorID];
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == Author)
                return;
            if (value == null)
            {
                authorId = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (value.Id == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                authorId = value.Id;
            }

            AssertCorrectAuthor(value);
        }
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    private void AssertCorrectAuthor(Author author)
    {
        if (store != null)
            Debug.Assert(author == Author);
    }

    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("store")]
public class Store
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, Book> books = new Dictionary<string, Book>();
    readonly Dictionary<string, Author> authors = new Dictionary<string, Author>();

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IDictionary<string, Book> Books
    {
        get
        {
            return books;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IDictionary<string, Author> Authors
    {
        get
        {
            return authors;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlArray("authors")]
    [XmlArrayItem("author")]
    public Author[] AuthorList // proxy array for serialization.
    {
        get
        {
            return Authors.Values.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (var author in authors.Values)
            {
                author.Store = null;
            }
            Authors.Clear();
            if (value == null)
                return;
            foreach (var author in value)
            {
                author.Store = this;
            }
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlArray("books")]
    [XmlArrayItem("book")]
    public Book[] BookList // proxy array for serialization.
    {
        get
        {
            return Books.Values.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (var book in Books.Values)
            {
                book.Store = null;
            }
            Books.Clear();
            if (value == null)
                return;
            foreach (var book in value)
            {
                book.Store = this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, to test:

```
public static class TestStore
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<store>
  <authors>
   <author id=""PK"">
     <name>Philip Kindred</name>
    </author>
  </authors>

  <books>
    <book id=""u1"">
      <author>PK</author> <!--  use only ID -->
      <title>Ubik</title>
    </book>
    <book id=""t1"">
      <author>PK</author> <!--  use only ID -->
      <title>The Transmigration of Timothy Archer</title>
    </book>
  </books>
</store>
";
        var store = xml.LoadFromXML<Store>();
        Debug.Assert(store.BookList[0].Author == store.AuthorList[0]); // no assert
        Debug.Assert(store.BookList[1].Author == store.AuthorList[0]); // no assert; verify that all books use the same instance of the `Author` class.
    }
}
```